# SNMP: Recover whole MIBtree with python using bulk command

Tags: android, python, snmp

I have a SNMP agent in android.
I'm trying to recover the whole MIBTree with this python script:

```
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen  


cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, \
varBinds = cmdGen.bulkCmd(  
        cmdgen.CommunityData('public', mpModel=0),  
        cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('192.168.0.90', 32150)), 
        0, 
        25, 
        (1,3,6,1,4,1,12619,1,1)
    )

if errorIndication:
    print(errorIndication)
elif errorStatus:
    print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                    errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'))
else:
    for varBind in varBinds:
    print(' = '.join([repr(x) for x in varBind]))
```

if I use the oid (1,3,6,1,4,1,12619,1,1) as the root oid, the output is this:

```
ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(ObjectName('1.3.6.1.4.1.12619.1.1.1.0')),OctetString('intel ICI101'))
ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(ObjectName('1.3.6.1.4.1.12619.1.1.2.0')),OctetString('4.4.4'))
ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(ObjectName('1.3.6.1.4.1.12619.1.1.3.0')), TimeTicks(10100333))
(ObjectIdentity(ObjectName('1.3.6.1.4.1.12619.1.2.1.0')), EndOfMibView())
```

It is working right. The problem is I want the whole MIB tree, so I want to use the root oid which is (1,3,6,1,4,1,12619,1). But the output using that OID is:

```
OIDs are not increasing
```

How can make this work?

Answer (score 0):

ignoreNonIncreasingOid = True

adding that parameter as an option made it work.

```
varBinds = cmdGen.bulkCmd(  
        cmdgen.CommunityData('public', mpModel=0),  
        cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('192.168.0.90', 32150)), 
        0, 
        25, 
        (1,3,6,1,4,1,12619,1),
        ignoreNonIncreasingOid = True
    )
```